# EF Code First: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've no idea why, but I get that error when I try to login into my EF Code First MVC application.

My home Controller has the `[Authorize]` attribute, so I get redirected straight to the login page, but once I login, I get the Yellow Screen of Death and the error:

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

**CODE**

Here my Context Code:

```
public class PdContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public PdContext() : base("PdContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
  {
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
  }

  public static PdContext Create()
  {
    return new PdContext();
  }

  public DbSet<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("PD");
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(r => r.Id).ToTable("AspNetRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.UserId, l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
  }
}
```

And here is the code in my Seed method that is responsible for creating my user and role.

```
protected override void Seed(Context.PdContext context)
{
  var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
  var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
  if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
  {
    roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
  }

  var adminUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "myemail@gmail.com", Email = "myemail@gmail.com" };

  if (userManager.FindByName("myemail@gmail.com") != null) return;

  var adminResult = userManager.Create(adminUser, "strongPassword");

  if (adminResult.Succeeded)
  {
    userManager.AddToRole(adminUser.Id, "Admin");
  }

  // other non user related seeding happening here
}
```

My connection string is as follows:

```
<add name="PdContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=My-PC;Initial Catalog=Phoneden;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=strongPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

I've checked, and I only have one connection string (my researching of the error suggested there might be two connection strings, there isn't in my case).

**UPDATE**

I've disabled the `[Authorize]` attribute just to check and see if the actual user was being created in the database. It turns out, that user isn't being created at all! Any ideas?

Comment: So, do you have only one database connection which has the required tables for Identity?

Comment: Yep. And when I check in SQL Management studio, all membership tables are there!

Comment: I have posted a potential solution to your problem. Have a try with it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Can you post how you built your context so we can take a look?

Comment: @DavidsonSousa I've added the context code

Comment: Did you change AspNetUsers table name (default user info table) To user?

Comment: I'm not sure, but what I have there, I did in another solution, yet I never got this problem I'm having now!

Comment: @MostafaEsmaeili what should the default table name be? Also, even if I have, I'm telling it to map to `User` table, so I would have thought, that wouldn't cause issues

Comment: @Ciwan .You should use `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                           .ToTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                          .ToTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");` .If you want to change default identity table name,You need to update database. `Enable-Migrations` and `Update-Database`

Comment: @MostafaEsmaeili yep, I already have Migrations enabled and I am updating the database, but still get the same error.

Comment: Ok. so bind IdentityUser:    `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");`

Comment: If You still get error  ، try to add a role by roleManager. does it works?

Comment: adding `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");` caused an error about migrations being disabled, when they are in fact enabled

Answer (score 0):

It might be a solution as easy as changing the Integrated Security attribute in the connection string to `True`. This is telling that the Identity tables are to be found and used in the provided database.

Therefore, your connection string would be:

```
<add name="PdContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=My-PC;Initial Catalog=Phoneden;Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa;Password=strongPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it made no difference. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You might have 2 different Contexts in your application, which is normal when we start with the standard ASP.NET MVC template. What I usually do is to remove the standard context and adapt the one I am creating (AppContext), as in the code below:

```
public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AppContext() : base("PdContext")
    {
    }
}
```

The catch is in the inheritance of `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, which makes the membership works in your custom context.

Comment: I checked and mine is inheriting from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, I've added code in original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this would work, but I deleted my Migrations folder, and cleaned my solution, then re-enabled Migrations and Added an `InitialCreate` Migration. Then did `Update-Database` and all seems to work now! :/